# Android XML resize / fit ImageButton different screens

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, screens

I made ImageButton menu design in the hopes that its size can adjust the screen:
but after I test using with smartphone 3-inch 320x480 
, 4-inch 480x800, 5-inch 720x1280, view ImageButton is mess.

I've tried using TableLayout, LinearLayout, GridLayout,
and FrameLayout, but the result is the same.

Thank you in advance.[This picture my trial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TOI0.png)

#### This my XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear1">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/title"
                android:contentDescription="title"/>
    </LinearLayout>


      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"              
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:tag="0"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagebutton4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"            
        android:background="@drawable/image" 
        android:tag="2"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"            
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:tag="4"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagebutton4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"            
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:tag="3"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:background="@drawable/image"   
        android:tag="1"
        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ib1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ib1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" 
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ib2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ib2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" 
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ib3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ib3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" 
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ib4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ib4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" 
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Plz provide layout for more clarity dear

Comment: You need to make images of different sizes: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You need to do some math on that specifically using the percentage approach/

Comment: You need to add images for different resolutions in order to show images of appropriate sizes on screen. If you are using android studio, then you can try plugins like **Batch drawable import** to add images of different densities in your app. Other option is to add svg and give width and height to image button.

Comment: @ Mohit Trivedi Thanks for comment . I use RelativeLayout , this my xml code already post. please correct

Comment: @Deepak Singh , i use eclipse and  i add button image in drawable-hdpi 108x108 , drawable-ldpi 48x48, drawable-mdpi 108x108, drawable-xhdpi 108x108, drawable-xxhdpi 108x108 , and i use RelativeLayout

Comment: @Enzokie What kind of example ? on top of the existing my xml code

Comment: @Ai Lelopath , i use eclipse and i add button image in drawable-hdpi 108x108 , drawable-ldpi 48x48, drawable-mdpi 108x108, drawable-xhdpi 108x108, drawable-xxhdpi 108x108 , and i use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

I created a scratch which will define layout with linear and weight

I hope it will help you out

Also attached code with screen shots
[image]

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer, I will try. please see my xml code screenshot

Comment: @MohitTrivedi: What software is that drawn in? :)

Comment: In notebook & capture from camera

Comment: @Johan here i make a layout refer it and told me if you require any problem & it will work on any device even in landscape also

Comment: @MohitTrivedi 
Thank you so much for your help ,
I've tried xml code from your
in smarthpone 3inch, 4inch, 5 inch, in the emulator with some
the size and the results are very satisfying.

-Sorry I want to ask again:
should I place the image size to ImageButton src
with different sizes
in drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi,
drawable-xxdpi or simply in drawable-hdpi only.

- and how sizes ideally ,like this or what?
drawable-hdpi (72 x 72)
drawable-ldpi (36 x 36)
drawable-mdpi (48 x 48)
drawable-xhdpi (96 x 96)
drawable-xxhdpi (144 x 144)

Comment: @MohitTrivedi 
-and for xml file, enough in layout or be added as well in
layout-large, small layout, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp.

Previous thank you very much for the answer, and ask
sorry a lot to ask.

Comment: @johan I m very glad to help you out. Yes you can put images in all drawable folders because whole layout is dynamic now so don't worry about this and if I talk with layout I don't think to make different layouts use this it will run almost all devices if in future you find a device in that layout should not look proper than you should go for that device specific layout otherwise for now it is prefect. Still if you face any issue feel free to ask. And please accept answer if you satisfied

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Thanks for your help, 
may god avenge your kindness